# Using Extended Find and Replace + Reg Expressions to find and remove an anchor tag in HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to use regular expressions to find and remove all anchor tags identical to these -

```
<a href="mms://media.domain.com/CHE/filename-1.wma">title name</a>  
<a href="mms://media.domain.com/CHE/filename.wma">title name part II</a>
```

Where ONLY the filename and titles change, and I need to leave the title (unlinked) behind.

Because of my word-processing background I naively tried the following wildcards in my extended find and replace with regular expressions checked:

```
<a href="mms://media.domain.com/CHE/*.wma">*</a>
```

it does not work of course, not even to remove the entire link and text.

After much searching and reading I'm still just guessing at how to do this.   Since no example I've found does exactly what I need using extended find and replace.  All of this is over my head.

I have searched "How To Use regular expressions in Search and Replace" with HomeSite, Dreamweaver, topsite and other similar software to what I'm using to edit my HTML docs. Without success. I've read several tutorials on using RegExp and I'm learning, but still cannot seem to do what I need. I have read how to use RegExp in php, perl, c++ but cannot transition this over to what I need.

I'm willing to use other text editing software to accomplish this as I need to remove about 4,000 of these wma file links, while leaving the titles and other tags untouched.

I have searched similar questions here on stackoverflow.  And read up on using regular expressions in general, but I cannot follow what is explained enough to adapt it to what I need.  This is such a big subject.

This is what I have so far:

```
<a href="mms:\/\/media\.domain\.com\/CME\/           \.wma">       <\/a>
```

The parts where I've left spaces are what's giving me trouble.

Thanks

Comment: Opps I forgot - I know enough to know I need to escape the special characters.  So this is what I have so far:  <a href="mms:\/\/media\.domain.com\/CME\/(\\[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+\.wma">*<\/a>

Answer (score 0):

With some help on a forum I was able to work out my answer, here it is

Find:

```
<a href="mms:\/\/media\.domain\.com\/WMA\/[^.]+.wma">([^<]+)</a>
```

Replace:

```
\1
```

Note the parenthesis around the [^<]+ this creates a sub-expression that can be referenced by the \1   I do not know how this all works exactly, but I found it in an article.

This find and replace finds my anchor tag and title and replaces it with just the title.
I have to give thanks to http://forums.devshed.com for the pieces I was missing.